# Is there a way to set up a mail form so the email address that is entered in the form is the reply to address

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to set up a mail form so the email address that is entered in the form is the reply to address? In that way when you hit reply in your email client it replies to the address that the person entered in the email line. Right now when you try to reply it goes to `no-reply@cognitoforms.com`.

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We will be including this feature in our December release. You will be able to set your email address so that all notification emails will be sent to you, you can also create an email address field and set that field as the 'From' for the email notification. By doing this you can respond using the notification as long as the user filling out the form has included a valid email address.

You can learn more about and follow the progress of this feature on our [Trello board](https://trello.com/c/GPZadDc0).

You can see an example of how this will look in the following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am part of the Cognito Forms team. We released the ability to [create custom email confirmations and notifications](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/20/building-forms/notification-emails) in this morning's release.